# Split a list of points into a list of lines in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of points (`System.Drawing.Point`) obtained from an edge finder function that scanned a bitmap for objects.  Each point is guaranteed to be a part of an edge line.  I need to split the list into a collection of lines so additional math can be performed on them.

This is how I originally split the list:

```
public static List<List<Point>> Split(this List<Point> EdgesCoordinateList)
{
    if (EdgesCoordinateList is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(EdgesCoordinateList), NullParameterErrorMessage); }
    if (EdgesCoordinateList.Count <= 1) { return null; }

    //  Link the line coordinates together into lines.
    //  Start by creating a new line with the first coordinate to act as a seed.
    List<List<Point>> Results = new List<List<Point>>
    {
        new List<Point> { EdgesCoordinateList[0] }
    };
    EdgesCoordinateList.RemoveAt(0);

    //  Iterate through the coordinates and assign each one to a line.
    foreach (Point TestPoint in EdgesCoordinateList)
    {
        //  Look through each previously found lines and see if the coordinate under test belongs to one of them.
        //  If coordinate under test is adjacent to one of the coordinates in the line under test, it belongs to that line.
        bool FoundLine = false;
        foreach (List<Point> LineList in Results.Where(LineList
            => LineList.FindLastIndex(i => Math.Abs(TestPoint.X - i.X) <= 1 && Math.Abs(TestPoint.Y - i.Y) <= 1) > -1))
        {
            //  Add the coordinate to the line it belongs to, then break the line search.
            Results[Results.IndexOf(LineList)].Add(TestPoint);
            FoundLine = true;
            break;
        }

        //  If line is not a part of preexisting lines then its the start of a new one.
        if (!FoundLine)
        { Results.Add(new List<Point> { TestPoint }); }
    }

    return Results;
}
```

It was great because it was fairly quick and worked well, except it messed up on lines that were relatively horizontal.

This is my second attempt to try to fix the issue:

```
public static List<List<Point>> Split(this List<Point> EdgesCoordinateList)
{
    if (EdgesCoordinateList is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(EdgesCoordinateList), NullParameterErrorMessage); }
    if (EdgesCoordinateList.Count <= 1) { return null; }

    //  Link the line coordinates together into lines.
    //  Start by creating a new line with the first coordinate to act as a seed.
    List<List<Point>> Results = new List<List<Point>>
    {
        new List<Point> { EdgesCoordinateList[0] }
    };
    EdgesCoordinateList.RemoveAt(0);

    do
    {
        //  Copy the currently found lines into a list for iterating.
        //  Outer list is a list of lines.  Inner list is a list of the points in each line.
        List<List<Point>> FoundLines = Results.ConvertAll(item => new List<Point>(item));
        bool NoMoreMatches = true;

        //  Iterate through the list of lines.
        for (int i = 0; i < FoundLines.Count; i++)
        {
            //  Iterate through each point in the current line.
            foreach (Point TestPoint in FoundLines[i])
            {
                //  Find all of the points in the master list that are adjacent to the current test point.
                List<Point> FoundCoords = EdgesCoordinateList.FindAll(i => Math.Abs(TestPoint.X - i.X) <= 1 && (Math.Abs(TestPoint.Y - i.Y) <= 1));

                if (FoundCoords.Count > 0)
                {
                    //  Add all of the adjacent points to the current line.
                    Results[i].AddRange(FoundCoords);

                    //  Then remove them from the master list.
                    foreach (Point Coord in FoundCoords)
                    { _ = EdgesCoordinateList.Remove(Coord); }

                    NoMoreMatches = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //  When there are no more adjacent points to any of the points in the current line, make another line.
        if (NoMoreMatches)
        {
            Results.Add(new List<Point> { EdgesCoordinateList[0] });
            EdgesCoordinateList.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //  Continue until there are no more points left in the master list.
    } while (EdgesCoordinateList.Count > 0);

    return Results;
}
```

The new solution solved the horizontal issue, but runs way too slow.  (It went from less than a second to several minutes.)

How can I refactor this to speed it up?  I would prefer it to work at least at a similar speed as the first method if possible.

---

**Edit:**  The following is a test method which will generate a list of coordinates.
When run through the split method, it will split the list into four lists of lines.  The actual data comes from 2-4K bitmaps, the lines of which can vary in thickness.  I am not sure how to provide an equivalent test method without it being convoluted.

`List<List<Point>> SourceData`
The outer list is a list of lines.  The inner list contains the points assigned to each line.

```
private List<Point> GenerateSourceData()
{
    List<Point> SourceData = new List<Point>();

    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(5000, 5050, 0, 30));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(5050, 5100, 30, 60));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(5100, 5150, 60, 90));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(5150, 5200, 90, 120));

    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(6000, 6050, 0, 30));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(6050, 6100, 30, 60));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(6100, 6150, 60, 90));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(6150, 6200, 90, 120));

    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(7100, 7130, 0, 30));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(7130, 7140, 30, 60));

    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(8100, 8120, 60, 90));
    SourceData.AddRange(AddPoints(8120, 8130, 90, 120));

    return SourceData;
}

private List<Point> AddPoints(int XStart, int XEnd, int YStart, int YEnd)
{
    List<Point> Data = new List<Point>();

    for (int Y = YStart; Y < YEnd; Y++)
    {
        for (int X = XStart; X < XEnd; X++)
        { Data.Add(new Point(X, Y)); }
    }

    return Data;
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**  I have found a way to reduce the time to approximately 30 seconds by slicing up the lists at various stages and using `Parallel.ForEach` to run all iterations of each stage simultaneously.  I am not posting the code here however because the basic operation is essentially the same.

I have tried using a couple methods I thought might work that do not involve deleting points from the source, but both introduced additional problems, including creating duplicates of most coordinates.  And although the parallel processing method is a major improvement, 30 seconds is still way too long.  Thus, I still seek help in exploring alternative routes in refactoring.

Comment: Have you used any sort of profiling tool like [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/) to find the bottleneck?

Comment: Just finished running CodeTrack, and as I suspected, most of the time is spent in FindAll, which is tucked away in 2 layers of loops.  This is what I am trying to refactor, as an hour plus is an unacceptable run time.  Still valuable though as this was the first time I have used one of these tools.

Comment: why are you modifying the source `EdgesCoordinateList` and also returning a new list at the same time ?

Comment: A lack of reproducible example. I have no idea how to test it, thus there's no way to make changes.

Comment: The reason for removing points from `EdgesCoordinateList` was to avoid possible duplicates and to avoid the possibility of iterating through data that had already been taken care of on previous cycles.  I know that you would typically not want to modify source data, but I could not think of another method of doing this.